# How to scroll a horizontal StackPanel in ScrollViewer?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, scrollviewer, stackpanel

I am new to wpf and i need help. i must show n vertical elements(stackpanels) horizontally. I used a horizontal stackpanel to put all n vertical stackpanels in it and i put horizontal stackpanel in a scrollviewer.
this is the xaml code below:

```
`<Window x:Class="Results.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Grid>
    <telerik:RadButton x:Name="radButton" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" Margin="407,66,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" Click="radButton_Click"/>
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer  Height="96" Margin="10,115,0,0"  Width="497" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <StackPanel x:Name="teststack" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="94" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="497" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Grid>`
```

This is c# code for generating n elements below(where col in vertical and teststack is horizontal):

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrowcount; i++)
{
    StackPanel col = new StackPanel();
    TextBox row = new TextBox();
    Image img = new Image();
    col.Children.Add(row);
    col.Children.Add(img);
    teststack.Children.Add(col);
}
```

[this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOwoS.png) is my unwanted result.because I put 20 elements to show but there is 12 elements to see without scrollbar. my ideal is a horizontal scrollbar be visible in this image under elements.
please suggest me an edit if I asked my problem in wrong way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try without `Height` and `Width` of `ScrollViewer`.

```
<ScrollViewer  Margin="10,115,0,0" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
     <StackPanel x:Name="teststack" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="94" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="497" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: @siamakwork: Is it working without height and width?